# is there any way to cache network content and management well by the cache system

Tags: network

Many website was blocked from my area, so I want some way to cache network resource to my local machine when I am offline from Inernete or VPN not avaliable. So at that time I could still access to some important resource I needed, for example some kubernetes article and images,or some videos, it needed to management well by the cache system, is there any good way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add them to reading list and have them offline.

https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/keep-a-reading-list-sfri35905/12.0/mac/10.14

> [image]

It gets tricker to work if it is synced across devices. So I tend to save pages I need using File menu > Export as PDF.. or Save as.. > Web Archive.

Often `wget -c site.com` is also helpful.

As pointed out by nohillside in comments, `youtube-dl` can save videos offline too, not just from YouTube, despite its name.

Both of the CLI tools can be managed by `brew`, cleanly.

- https://brew.sh

Comment: `youtube-dl` (and its UI-based siblings) are the way to go for videos